# Some problems about charcodeat in JavaScript ,0xd7ff,0xe000,0x35fdc00

Tags: javascript, typescript, unicode

what's the meaning of `0xd7ff`,`0xe000`,and  `(code << 10) + next - 0x35fdc00` ?

```
const nonASCIIwhitespace = /[\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]/

const fullCharCodeAtPos = (input: string, pos: number) => {
  if (String.fromCharCode) return input.codePointAt(pos)
  const code = input.charCodeAt(pos)
  if (code <= 0xd7ff || code >= 0xe000) return code

  const next = input.charCodeAt(pos + 1)
  return (code << 10) + next - 0x35fdc00
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `(code <= 0xd7ff || code >= 0xe000)` is *true* if and only if the `code` isn't a [surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates), see [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt):

> ```
> …
> D800;<Non Private Use High Surrogate, First>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DB7F;<Non Private Use High Surrogate, Last>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DB80;<Private Use High Surrogate, First>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DBFF;<Private Use High Surrogate, Last>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DC00;<Low Surrogate, First>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DFFF;<Low Surrogate, Last>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> …
> ```

Surrogates are between `0xD800` (`== 0xd7ff + 1`) and `0xDFFF` (`== 0xe000 - 1`).

---

The formula `(code << 10) + next - 0x35fdc00` decodes UTF-16 surrogate pair `code`, `next` to code point (above [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode))).

This formula is another form of more comprehensible

`0x10000 + ((code - 0xD800) << 10) + (next - 0xDC00)`

(found in [The WTF-8 encoding](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) excellent article).

Comment: Both formulas mentioned above are equivalent as (eliminating variables `code` and `next`): `0x10000 + (-0xD800 << 10) -0xDC00 == -0x35fdc00` evaluates to `true`…